# What do you call a person who makes maille?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who makes maille (chainmail)? Would they be just be called an armor smith, or is there a more specific term that is widely accepted? I have heard "chain mailer", and while most people would understand, it is not a term I would consider very accurate, since many people consider "chain mail" wrong, and prefer "maille" or "mail". Is there a more accurate or historically correct term that I can use? Is "mailmaker" usable?

An example usage would be: "I have a friend who is a ________, and he made a hauberk for me."

Answer (score 1):

The general term "armourer", meaning a smith who specializes in the production of armor, may be used. Alternatively, depending on context, the Middle English term ["hauberǧer"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED20120) from Old French haubergier) more specifically means what you want, which is to say, a maker of maille armours. The former term is far better known, while the latter has long fallen out of use almost entirely, except appearing still as a surname.